# Why $\int_{1}^{\infty} e^{-x} dx$ converges but $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x} dx$ does not?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, infinity

I'm struggling to intuitively understand the above. They both have similar shape and have an asymptote at y = 0, why is it that the exponential converges but the hyperbola diverges?

Comment: if you even see the value of $e^x$ at $100$ you can see how fast it goes

Comment: It's just so unintuitive to me that the determining factor of whether the integral is finite or not depends on the rate the function approaches 0. I understand the argument, but why should that matter?  Ultimately, they both go on infinitely

Comment: Intuitively the decreasing rate of a function is the **only** thing that can matter for the (absolute) convergence of the improper integral, is not it?

Comment: $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x}$ and $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^{1.00001}}$ have also “similar shape” :)

Comment: Just see the graph of these two functions : $e^{-x}$ decreases so fast that the area under the curve is finite, whereas $1/x$ is too slow, so this makes the area under the curve infinite.

Comment: @GaryAllen Rates matter. Why would the harmonic sum diverge but $\zeta(2)$ converge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saying *"they both have similar shape"* is not a reasonable description.  It is true that the two functions both decrease towards $0$, but $e^{-x}$ (blue in the first graph below) falls much faster towards $0$ than $\frac1x$ (red) does.

It is visibly plausible that the area below the blue curve extended to the right may be finite while the area below the red curve extended to the right may not be.

[image]

If you do the partial integrals then you can confirm this, since  $\int\limits_1^y e^{-x} \, dx = e^{-1}-e^{-y}$ and $\int\limits_1^y \frac1x \, dx = \log_e(y)$.  Visually you can then see that the blue integral rapidly approaches an upper bound when $y$ increases, while the red integral keeps increasing, albeit at a slightly decreasing rate.

[image]

Comment: The downvote isn't right.

Answer (score 1):

It is a matter of how fast the function tends to zero. Exponential decay is very fast.

$$\int_n^{n+1}e^{-x}dx=e^{-1}\int_{n-1}^ne^{-x}dx$$ and you have a decreasing geometric series.

Harmonic decrease is slow.

$$\int_n^{2n}\frac{dx}x=\int_{n/2}^n\frac{dx}x$$ and you add an infinity of constant terms.

---

If you consider

$$\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{x^a}=\left.\frac{x^{1-a}}{1-a}\right|_1^\infty$$ you understand that a critical exponent is $a=1$. Hence $\dfrac1x$ is slightly too slow to converge.